# IEEE 754 identity laws: Literal meaning and value-changing optimizations

Tags: floating-point, nan, ieee-754

The IEEE 754-2008 standard says for expressions like `0 + x` and `1 * x` that the identity property may be applied (§ 10.4):

> Applying the identity property 1 × x when x is not a signaling NaN and the result has the same exponent as x.

I'm wondering what does "the result has the same exponent as x" mean?

Comment: IEEE 754-2008 includes decimal formats where numbers may be representable in multiple ways with different exponents, such as .123•10^3 and 123•10^0 (examples for illustration, not necessarily directly from an IEEE 754 format). The different representations of the same number are the number’s *cohort*.  IEEE 754-2008 5.2 contains this: “Thus for finite x, depending on the representation of zero, 0+x might result in a different member of x’s cohort.”

Comment: Uhh yeah I always ignored base-10 FP numbers. Since the identity property is defined for binary as well as decimal numbers, the extra notion makes sense now. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they mean the exponent field of the binary representation.

Multiplying by 1 doesn't change the exponent even for a QNaN, even if the significand (NaN payload) changes.  All NaNs have the same all-ones exponent encoding.  (Infinity is all-ones exponent with significand=0; the entire rest of the coding space for that exponent value is spent on NaN payloads which basically nobody uses.)

For any non-NaN, it's trivially true that the exponent field doesn't change when you multiply by 1.  Neither does the significand or sign bit.  (IIRC, `1.0 * -0.0 = -0.0`).

Comment: Naively I would assume that the whole bit pattern is not changed. Independend if it is a number or a quiet NaN. What could be the thought behind it that the significand of a quiet NaN changes?

Comment: @MaxMaier: Good question, I think you're right that the NaN payload doesn't change unless both inputs are NaN; then you might get either.  (Yup, [NAN propagation and IEEE 754 standard](//stackoverflow.com/q/49011370) says as much).